# Sql query speed (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Good day! I tried to take some data from MySQL, but my query was doing for more than 1 second. My query has to take from MySQL information about files' categories and categories of this ones. I guess, that's a bad result, isn't it? Are there any ways to solve this problem? In my php scripts I use pdo

Comment: Can you show the query and some sample data? Does really the query take this long or is it the whole processing from start to end? How many rows are in your tables? A lot of things we need to know to be able to help

Comment: Ok. My query:  'SELECT id, name FROM `categ` WHERE `pid` = ?'/

Comment: It is the whole processing from start to end . I have 6 rows in my table

Comment: There are two main rows in my table: 'categ' - all main categories are here and  'pidcateg' - all categories of selected main category keep here

Comment: can you use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create a sandbox with your structure and data?

Comment: HERE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00029/1/0

Comment: Alright, so as you see, the execution time of the query is ok. You will need to show some of your code. Pls edit your question to add the link to the fiddle and to add the code formatted